# ROPC flow: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'

Tags: python, azure-ad-msal

I am testing MSAL and ROPC flow. When I run sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-desktop I get error:

```
python username_password_sample.py parameters.json
invalid_client
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
```

I was having same problem while following MS documentation and used *curl*. Please check [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200589/how-to-log-on-to-user-mailbox-from-service-using-oauth-and-ms-graph-api/61202110?noredirect=1#comment108305759_61202110) where SO community helped me to solve problem. After adding application registration secret to curl request, I got valid token and I was able to fetch mails.
What is confusing me is fact that **secret** is not present in *parameters.json* file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve the error AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client\_secret' or 'client\_assertion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609432/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-aadsts70002-the-request-body-must-contain-the-follow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the step No.6 from this link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-desktop/tree/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithUsernamePassword

[image]

If the application was set as `Public Client`, then the secret is not required.

For more details, you can read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
Now I looked carefully at text:  
"Required for the use of the following flows where a redirect URI is not used:​
    Resource owner password credential"  
That is exactly scenario I am using.  
I first tested with curl and it worked when I added client_secret to body. It means this is not mandatory for ROPC without redirect URL.